# Want to find name and maximum marks scored subject from a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I have a table variable and I want to find every student name with there maximum scored subject.

```
declare @test1 table (name varchar(50), english int, math int, science int)

insert into @test1(name, english, math, science)
select 'A', 50, 90, 70
union all 
select 'B', 60, 80, 65
union all 
select 'C' , 80,65, 70
union all 
select 'D', 70, 75, 89
```

Please if any one can help me out, that would be appreciable.

Comment: Hint:  `row_number()`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one trick to do this

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties NAME,
                       sub_name,
                       mark
FROM   @test1
       CROSS apply (VALUES(english,'english'),
                          (math,'math'),
                          (science,'science'))tc(mark, sub_name)
ORDER  BY Row_number()OVER(partition BY NAME ORDER BY mark DESC)
```

or use ugly looking `CASE`statement but this will perform better then `Cross Apply`

```
SELECT NAME,
       sub_name,
       CASE sub_name
         WHEN 'english' THEN english
         WHEN 'math' THEN math
         ELSE science
       END mark
FROM   (SELECT *,
               CASE
                 WHEN english > math AND english > science THEN 'english'
                 WHEN english < math AND math > science THEN 'math'
                 ELSE 'science'
               END AS sub_name
        FROM   @test1) a
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to use apply, if not possible.

Comment: @RaviShukla - Updated with `CASE` statement

Comment: @RaviShukla Why not APPLY ?

Comment: Thanks. But I was not looking for case.

Comment: @RaviShukla - What else restrictions you have :D. Good luck finding answer

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want APPLY, perhaps UNPIVOT

```
Declare @test1 table (name varchar(50), english int, math int, science int)
insert into @test1(name, english, math, science)
select 'A', 50, 90, 70 union all select 'B', 60, 80, 65 union all  select 'C' , 80,65, 70 union all  select 'D', 70, 75, 89

Select Top 1 with Ties 
       Name,SubjectName,Score
From   @test1 A
unpivot ( Score for SubjectName in ( english, math, science) ) u
Order by Row_number() Over (Partition By Name Order By Score Desc)
```

Retruns

```
Name    SubjectName  Score
A       math         90
B       math         80
C       english      80
D       science      89
```

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I have some restriction so this one would be good.

Comment: I think his professor told him "you didn't write this because we haven't covered that" @Prdp

Answer (score 1):

Prdp's `Cross Apply` would be my first choice (+1).  BUT, if you don't want to specify all the fields, here a a slightly more dynamic approach via `XML` and a `CROSS APPLY` (or two)

```
Declare @test1 table (name varchar(50), english int, math int, science int)
insert into @test1(name, english, math, science)
select 'A', 50, 90, 70 union all select 'B', 60, 80, 65 union all  select 'C' , 80,65, 70 union all  select 'D', 70, 75, 89

Select Top 1 with Ties 
       A.Name
      ,C.*
 From  @test1 A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData= cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('name','otherfields')  --<< field names are case sensitive
             ) C
 Order by Row_number() Over (Partition By Name Order By Value Desc)
```

Returns

```
Name    Item    Value
A       math    90
B       math    80
C       english 80
D       science 89
```